# Trouble with date returned from API

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, datetime, timezone

First off, I am a novice level programmer, I apologize if this is not clear.
The API I am hitting is returning "createdDate: 20190216T070519.000Z" or "EndTime: 20190217T190847.181Z" I can't figure out how in C# to convert this to DateTime.

This is returned as a string and I get

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I tried something like this but I have no way of knowing the source format or what this .000Z stands for, I suspect its a timezone.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(createdDate, "yyyyMMddpHHmmss.fffZ",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

also did this thinking it would help but not sure what to do with the `createdDate.Substring(16, 3)` part.

```
MessageBox.Show(createdDate.Substring(0, 8) +" @ "+ createdDate.Substring(9, 6) + " @ " + createdDate.Substring(16, 3));
```

Just looking at it, It might be a python format of `%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%fZ` but not sure as I am not familiar with Python but some searches online makes me think it is close.  Also seems it is time zone and maybe a diff from UTC or something.  I don't want my program to have the wrong date time information so if anyone can help me figure this out that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z means UTC. If there was a timezone other than UTC it would usually be specified as an offset -600 or something along those lines

as for your date parsing you were close:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(createdDate,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss.fffK",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

C# uses the K to stand for 'Kind' which can be UTC or Local or undefined

some people are sticklers and would say that you need to put the T in single quotes 'T' like so,

```
DateTime.ParseExact(createdDate,"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.fffK",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but to be honest, I find that confusing...

Comment: That was exactly what I needed and I was so close. I didn't understand the f and k relationship with what I was looking at.  Makes so much more since now. Thank you very much.

Comment: One also needs to pass either `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind`, or the combined `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` - otherwise while the `K` will match the `Z` in the string, the result will still be adjusted to the local time zone.   (I prefer `RoundTripKind` personally).  Also, this mess is avoided if you use a `DateTimeOffset` instead. ;)